# Using foreach in arraylist with items that have parameters C#

Tags: c#, arraylist

I want to iterate through an ArrayList that I've added objects to.

```
// in Duck : Animal class
public Duck(string name, Gender gender, int age) : base(name, gender, age) { }
public static Duck duck1 = new Duck ("Dolly", Gender.Female, 8); 

// in Animal class
private static ArrayList animalList = new ArrayList() 
{
Duck.duck1
};
```

In console app I want to be able to do this:

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        foreach (var item in AnimalList)
            Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
    }

// desired output:
Dolly
```

But since I added duck1, it prints the path " NewPondLibrary.Pond+Animal+Duck " I'm totally lost on how to achieve what I want, is adding objects to array like this just not possible? I added Duck.duck1 to the arraylist because I don't know another way to add objects to an array WITH parameters from the constructor.

The tutorials I looked at only show arraylists that have just a string or int item and no other information. I'm also curious how arraylist can be useful if just one line of information is all you can add. I'm very new to C# so might be missing some key theory.
Would appreciate any help

Comment: Are there any special reasons why you want to use `ArrayList` instead of `List<Animal>`?

Comment: @SomeBody I read that ArrayList size increases dynamically, I thought it would be a good idea because I want users to be able to add their own animals to the list through console app. (and I could use Queue for this)

Comment: Any reasons why this all has to be "static"? Just use regular instance classes like usual - you won't run into any such problem there at all

Comment: @nepdev when I remove static, I get errors "an object reference is required" in my class library and "the name x does not exist in current context" in my console app. I'm creating the objects in class library, accessing them in separate file.

Comment: @caxap `List` size increases dynamically too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `ArrayList` has items of type `Object` that's why this doesn't compile

```
// Doesn't compile: item is of type Object, not Duck
foreach (var item in AnimalList)
  Console.WriteLine(item.Name); // item is of type Object, not Duck
```

You can change `ArrayList` into `List<Duck>`:

```
private static List<Duck> animalList = new List<Duck>() {
  Duck.duck1
};
```

If you insist on using *obsolete* `ArrayList` you can filter `Duck`s either with a help of Linq

```
using System.Linq;

...

foreach (var item in AnimalList.OfType<Duck>())
  Console.WriteLine(item.Name); // item is of type Object
```

or without:

```
foreach (var item in AnimalList)
  if (item is Duck duck)
    Console.WriteLine(duck.Name);
```

Comment: It worked with List! Thank you. It makes more sense to use it.. I now have 
`public static List<Animal> AnimalList = new List<Animal>() {
Duck.duck1,
Frog.frog1
}; ` that outputs ` Dolly Froggy ` with `foreach (var Animal in AnimalList)Console.WriteLine(Animal.Name); ` Animal works, but I'm not sure if that's because I nested the classes Duck and Frog within Animal, or because I derived them from Animal.

Comment: @caxap It works because your classes are derived from Animal. This (very important) concept is called polymorphism.

Comment: `List<Animal>` will do if `Duck` inherits from `Animal` (i.e. if duck is animal) and `Animal` has `Name` property (or field)